# Preload specific component in angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am quite new to Angular and perhaps missing some obvious solution. When application goes offline I cannot display component AlertComponent, because of obvious offline error (ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 22 failed). If this component was already diplayed before going offline then everything works as expected - scripts are loaded for this component and even after going offline the alert is displayed. So the question is how to preload this component to be accessible after going offline?? Or some other solution is better?

As I understand the preloading strategy **PreloadAllModules** does not apply in this situation because it preloads components defined for routing.

I use ionic 5.5.2, angular 10

Comment: Please share your code which causes error

Comment: I don't think I got it quite right, but do you mean you Alert component is only loaded when (for whatever reason) it has been load before this offline event, and then it can be shown at the right time? Well, problably you have it set in some well structured component tree on your code... So the easy (said then done) part is put it "off" as possible from anything, and use some kind of notification or subject behavior change to make it usable, whenever you need

Comment: Yes, AlertComponent can be loaded in offline mode only when it has beed loaded before offline event. I am not sure what you mean - should I try to use this AlertComponent when online in order to load scripts from server for this component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to add offline capabilities to your website or web application is to turn it into a "progressive web app". Specifically you need to add a service worker to pre-fetch and cache required (static) resources.

Angular already has support for service workers. You can add a service worker to your app with the following command:

```
$ ng add @angular/pwa --project *project-name*
```

See the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started) for details.

Comment: I am aware of this solution, but it seems to be like take a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Comment: This sledgehammer was made to crack this nut :).

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the sledgehammer :) as shared by @rveerd. That said below is an approach that should also work

1. Declare the component in a module.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule, RouterModule.forChild([])],
  declarations: [LoadedComponent]
})
```

2. Load the Module as a lazy loaded module.

```typescript
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./loaded-component/loaded-component.module').then(
            m => m.LoadedComponentModule
          )
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

3. Now the component is loaded.

NB: I haven't tested the approach, But I believe since the component is declared in a module, whenever you load the module to another module, this should be available

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-srmd4d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)